# add key to associative array if key is not found

Tags: php

Given a PHP associative array like this one:

```
$a = array(
    'color' => 'red',
    'taste' => 'sweet',
    'shape' => 'round',
    'name'  => 'apple'
);
```

I want to search a key and, if not found, I want to add 'myKey'=>0. Which is the best way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are looking for the [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) function:

```
if (!array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
    $arr[$key] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 ways, if you are sure your keys CAN'T have NULLs, then you can use the ISSET()

```
if(!isset($a['keychecked'])){
    $a['keychecked'] = 0;
}
```

BUT, if you have NULLS in your array. You HAVE to use array_key_exists() which is longuer to write but not subjet to the isset(NULL) == false rule.

```
if(!array_key_exists('keychecked', $a)){
    $a['keychecked'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if( !isset($a['myKey'])) $a['mkKey'] = 0;
```

Or

```
$a['myKey'] = $a['myKey'] ? $a['myKey'] : 0;
```

Or

```
$a['myKey'] = (int) $a['myKey']; // because null as an int is 0
```

Comment: Your code may potentially display `E_NOTICE` errors, which is never a good idea if you can help it.

Comment: No, it throws `E_NOTICE`s if `error_reporting` doesn't exclude them.

Comment: That said, it could mess up things if `myKey` is set to something like an empty string... looks like the first option is best there, unless you know specifically what cases may arise.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$a = array( 'color' => 'red',
        'taste' => 'sweet',
        'shape' => 'round',
        'name'  => 'apple');
$key = 'myKey';
if (!array_key_exists($key, $a)) {
    $a[$key] = 0;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [null coalesce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) operator if you don't store `null` values:

```
$a['myKey'] ??= 0;
```

Note that if the key `myKey` already exists with a `null` value, then the above statement will override that value.